# Jira - hook before posting message

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is it possible to check message and suggest some corrections before posting in thread?

I didn't write any plugins for Jira before, and now need to check if in body of message some code with fields like password or pwd, to suggest remove this fields.

Comment: Do you mean comment under issue?

Comment: Yes, i want to check before submit.

Comment: It is possible to listen for issue events, in your case EventType.ISSUE_COMMENTED_ID and check the content. But this would be without possibility of user interaction, it's just a code that does some work on comment that is being submitted.